# Sorting NSSet throws exception valueForUndefinedKey

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to sort an NSSet of NSManagedObjects.  The value for one of the set item's "pubDate" property is nil. The following code throws an exception [NSManagedObject valueForUndefinedKey] when it is sorted.  How can I get it to ignore the element without a value for that key?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortNameDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"pubDate" ascending:NO] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortNameDescriptor, nil];
return [[self.items allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Are you sure every key in `self.items` has the key "pubdate"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he knows they don't all have it and wants to know how to get around that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sort objects on a value that doesn't exist. Can you give it a default value? It's like trying to sort the array `{1, 5, 3, X, 9, 7}`, you just can't unless you tell it how to deal with X.